# Accessibility props best practices - role or accessibilityRole?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, accessibility

[role](https://reactnative.dev/docs/accessibility#role) and [accessibilityRole](https://reactnative.dev/docs/accessibility#accessibilityrole) both communicate the purpose of a component to the user of an assistive technology. `role` has precedence over the `accessibilityRole` prop. For simple use cases where we don't anticipate overriding roles, but cannot use semantic elements, which is best practice to use?

e.g. For this non-semantic TouchableOpacity button:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  accessible={true}
  accessibilityRole="button"
  onPress={...}
>
...
</TouchableOpacity>
```

or

```
<TouchableOpacity
  accessible={true}
  onPress={...}
  role="button"
>
...
</TouchableOpacity>
```